# Oracle Apex Change date picker format

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

The current datepicker in Apex 20.1 looks like this:

[image]

However, is there a way to change its format to how a datepicker actually is in our laptops/systems?
i.e. id i click on June it'd show all the months to choose from and if i choose 2021, it'd show all years to choose from.

This would reduce moving monthwise to reach a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the settings of your datepicker, you should be able to select month/year 'Navigation List for'.

[image: show navigation list for]

This will render the month/year as select lists, and will honour the min/max date settings.

[image: date picker runtime]

Note, these options appear differently in 21.1

[image: 21.1 settings]

Comment: Ha! Just checked what my Apex says. Interestingly, I picked DATE column in Interactive Grid and it **does not** have those options, hence my answer that "I don't know how to do that". Looks like "standalone" DATE item's settings differ from "interactive grid" ones.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way, I don't know it.

What you could do, is to search for a plugin.

- Benefit: you might find what you're looking for.
- Drawback: sometimes, plugins are written and never maintained so they become *obsolete* and you can't use them in future Apex versions (unless you're capable of maintaining them yourself).

A simple workaround: **type** date, manually. You don't have to waste your time on clicking through a calendar to reach e.g. 22.06.1941; you'll be much, much faster if you actually press those 10 keyboard keys, `22.06.1941`. Takes 3 seconds at most.